# nginx not accepting POST form data

Tags: post, nginx

When i POST to server with this

```
POST /api/user/login HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

it works, but not this

```
POST /api/user/login HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

is it possible to get the first one work?

Comment: While the Content-Type header is optional in the HTTP spec, it seems that the code behind /api/user/login expects it. You could potentially work around it by forcing the content-type header using http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule

Comment: @BenGrimm no, it doesn't work.

Comment: It's a problem with the code handling that POST, not nginx. It may be worthwhile to edit the question and include that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both of them were working, the thing that blocked me was

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

I changed those lines so that my application can handle `500 502 503 504` errors.

**Now removed those lines and its working as expected.** Might help somebody